# Euler characteristic and Phase rule? Is there a connection between them?

Tags: geometric-topology

Eulers characteristic states

$$Vertices+Faces=Edges+2$$

Gibbs' phase rule states

$$ (\text{degrees of Freedom}) + (\text{no. of Phases}) = (\text{no. of Components}) + 2$$